# MVC3 Razor routing from Area to Root

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have searched the site and cant find anything similar to my question. I am new to MVC so I may be asking a dumb question.

When the site is launched there are default Home and About buttons at the top. I added a new button that points to an Area, that works just fine.

When I hover over the Home and About buttons after I go to the View that is in my Area, they links on them show they are now pointing to my Area and not the root of my project.

How do I tell these buttons to still point to the root and not my Area?

Thanks for any help or words of wisdom someone will be providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supposed to take you to root folder.

```
 @Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new { area = "" });
```

Okay I forgot to ask you what the routes look like in your global.asax.cs file? I've got a similar setup, and here are my route definitions

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", 
               action = "MaintainLists", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                             // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",          // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // defaults
        );
```

Comment: Hi DisplacedGuy,

Sorry about that post, I got pulled away in the middle of it and I couldnt edit it.

I think I am not understanding something.

This is in my root/_Layout.cshtml
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Excel Upload", "Create", "Excel", new { area = "Matrix" }, null)</li>

When I go to my "Area" the Home and About buttons want to send me to somewhere in my area and not to my root. Am I missing something somewhere. I dont understrand how to make the Home and About buttons point to my root.

Comment: What logic do you have in your ExcelController ?  I've tried the above code in one of my apps like <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li> 
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Excel Upload", "Index", "Tenant", new { area = "Matrix" }, null)</li>, which uses my TenantController and the Home and About still work fine.

Comment: This is what I have in my global.asax.cs
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =       UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );